# Latest 100 mentions - Twitter api

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm looking to achieve the following:

For a specific person, for example BarackObama, I'd like to get the **last 100 times/tweets he was mentioned**. Not his own tweets but the tweets of others containing @BarackObama.
In the end I'd like to have: the person who mentioned, location, datetime.
This content should be written **to a flat file**.

I've been experimenting with the Twitter API and Python, with success but haven't yet succeeded achieving the above problem.

I know there is a dev sections on the twitter website but they don't provide any example of code!!
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions
count=100 ....

For me the scripting language or way of doing is not relevant it's the result. I just read on the internet that python and Twitter api are a good match.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you should be using the [GET search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) instead of `GET statuses/mentions` as `statuses/mentions` is relative to the authenticating user.

Just use the username, in this case `@BarackObama` as the search term and it should yield what you're looking for.

As for sample code, you can look at projects like [Python-Twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) which have already built libraries around the Twitter API so you don't have to roll your own unless you really need to.

Comment: Python-Twitter is not python 3 compatible (as is Tweepy in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, indeed GET is the way to go

Comment: @Christian, maybe there's no need to add a new question but do you have a clue why this is only returning the last 100 results for BarackObama while I use rpp=1500: I'd expect 1500;  [link http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=BarackObama](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=BarackObama&rpp=1500&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed)

Comment: As the docs state `rpp - The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.` You will need to add the `page` parameter and page through your 15 pages of 100 results each. `The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page).`

Comment: Ok! Thanks Christian. That's what I thought but I find it quite limited like this

Comment: It's done so that you can't flood Twitter with sizeable requests and degrading the service for other users.

Answer (score 1):

The [`tweepy` module](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) is not Python 3 compatible, but should give you a good start on how to talk to the Twitter API from python.

Essentially, the Twitter API is called over HTTP and returns JSON, so you'll need to read up on the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html) and either the [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html) or the [`http.client`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.client.html) modules (`tweepy` uses the python 2 equivalent of the `http.client` module, [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)).

Note that the API method you link to, `mentions`, does not give you arbitrary mentions, only those for the *current twitter user*. So if I were to log in, it would show mentions for `@zopatista`. To show mentions for `@BarakObama` you'd have to do a search for that string via the [`search` API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) instead.

Comment: Dank je! Thanks. I'm almost there with your code hints. (I just don't see the output file 'twitter.json'....   http://pastebin.com/r2iCkVQR

Comment: Alsjeblieft! Better make that a new question with details on how that goes wrong; that fits much better with the SO format (it's not a support forum).